# AutoFollow using EntitySubscription

Tags: trigger, bulkification, entitysubscription

I'm trying to write a bulkified logic for a problem on entity subscription. I've a custom object Student which has custom lookup field to User named as Mentor. The use case is when the mentor field is populated with anyone he/she automatically becomes the follower of that student in chatter. If someone comes back to a student record and changes the mentor then the follower needs also to be changed i.e the follower has to be updated with the new mentor on student record in chatter. I've written a trigger for this which is working fine but I'm sure it won't work in case of a set of records because I haven't followed bulk design patterns. Here's the code I've written , I need help in modifying this code to allow this to work on a set of records.

```
  trigger StudentEntitySubscriptionTrigger1 on Student__c (after insert,after update) {

    List<EntitySubscription> stdEntitySubList = new List<EntitySubscription>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
    for(Student__c std:trigger.new){

        EntitySubscription stdEntity = new EntitySubscription();
        stdEntity.ParentId = std.Id;
        stdEntity.SubscriberId = std.Mentor__c;
        stdEntitySubList.add(stdEntity);
     }

        insert stdEntitySubList;
  }
  if(trigger.isUpdate){

      List<EntitySubscription> stdEntitySubList1 = new List<EntitySubscription>();

      //delete subscription;

      for(Student__c std:trigger.new){

            delete[ SELECT ID FROM EntitySubscription where ParentId=:std.Id
                                        ];

              EntitySubscription e = new EntitySubscription();
              e.ParentId = std.Id;
              e.SubscriberId = std.Mentor__c;
              stdEntitySubList1.add(e);
          }


      insert stdEntitySubList1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my code to follow bulk design pattern. I guess this will do fine.

```
   trigger StudentEntitySubscriptionTrigger1 on Student__c (after insert,after update) {

    List<EntitySubscription> stdEntitySubList = new List<EntitySubscription>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
    for(Student__c std:trigger.new){

        EntitySubscription stdEntity = new EntitySubscription();
        stdEntity.ParentId = std.Id;
        stdEntity.SubscriberId = std.Mentor__c;
        stdEntitySubList.add(stdEntity);
     }

        insert stdEntitySubList;
  }
  if(trigger.isUpdate){

      List<EntitySubscription> stdEntitySubListUpdate = new List<EntitySubscription>();
      List<Student__c> stdList = new List<Student__c>();

      for (Student__c std:Trigger.new) {
        Student__c oldStudent = Trigger.oldMap.get(std.ID);
        if (std.Mentor__c != oldStudent.Mentor__c) {
            stdList.add(std);
            }
         }        

       //delete subscription;
       delete[select id from EntitySubscription where ParentId IN :stdList];


       for(Student__c std : stdList){
            EntitySubscription e = new EntitySubscription();
            e.ParentId = std.Id;
            e.SubscriberId = std.Mentor__c;
            stdEntitySubListUpdate.add(e);
        }

      insert stdEntitySubListUpdate;
  }
}
```